# Delphi - arrays of interfaced objects - crashes

Tags: delphi

When using objects inherited from `TNoRefCountObject` and storing them in arrays, Delphi will crash because `_DynArrayClear` tries to free the interface via `_IntfClear`

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Generics.Collections, System.Classes;

type
  IMyList=interface ['{815633B4-5407-4AED-9A93-44DA7E609801}']
  end;

  TMyList=class(TNoRefCountObject, IMyList)
  public
  end;

var
  MyListArray:array of IMyList;
begin
  try
    SetLength(MyListArray,10);

    for var i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      MyListArray[i]:=TMyList.Create;
      FreeAndNil(MyListArray[i] as TMyList);
    end;

    SetLength(MyListArray,0);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

It does not always crash, but if I have a memory manager activated, it will tell me every time, that a dead interface is called when setting the length of the array to 0.

It will work, if the array is defined like this: `MyListArray: array of TMyList`

I would like to avoid casting the array elements later, as the assignment of the list in our code is done via other interfaced functions returning `IMyList`.

Any ideas how to get this working? Why is `_InftClear` called on `TNoRefCountObject`?

Answer (score 7):

> Why is _InftClear called on TNoRefCountObject?

It is called because you are storing interface references in an array and interface references are always reference counted. Compiler will always insert `_AddRef` and `_Release` calls in appropriate places when dealing with an interface reference, regardless of the actual reference counting implementation in the class.

In other words, it is the implementation within the class `_AddRef` and `_Release` methods that determines whether the instance memory will be managed through reference counting or not.

When you are dealing with instances of classes that have reference counting disabled, when you manually free such instance, you must be sure that at that time there is no interface reference pointing to that object, because when such interface goes out of scope or reference counting is triggered on it in some other way, that will call reference counting methods on already destroyed object which can cause the crash.

When you store object references in an array, you have no issues because object references don't trigger reference counting mechanism.

The problem happens in your loop, where you call `FreeAndNil`

```
  FreeAndNil(MyListArray[i] as TMyList);
```

In array you have interface reference to an object, but to call `FreeAndNil` you are typecasting it to an object reference and then that implicit (hidden) object reference is passed to the `FreeAndNil` procedure, not the array item location.

So you are freeing an object, but there is still a active interface reference to that object which will be cleared with `_IntfClear` (which calls `_Release` on non nil reference) when you set array length to 0, or when it goes out of scope.

To fix this you need to nil the interface reference first, and then free the object:

```
var
  Tmp: TMyList;
  
  for var i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    MyListArray[i]:=TMyList.Create;

    Tmp := TMyList(MyListArray[i]);
    MyListArray[i] := nil;
    Tmp.Free;
  end;
```

---

However, if you are storing those objects as interfaces, much better and safer solution would be to use `TInterfacedObject` as a base class instead of `TNoRefCountObject` and let reference counting manage those objects memory. That way you will avoid issues like the one you have shown here.

Then if you no longer need those objects you just need to clear the array by setting its length to 0, or you can also just set particular item in an array to nil. Your code would be simpler and cleaner.

```
TMyList=class(TInterfacedObject, IMyList)


SetLength(MyListArray,10);
for var i := 0 to 9 do
begin
  MyListArray[i]:=TMyList.Create;
end;
SetLength(MyListArray,0);
```

Comment: Assigning nil to a non-nil interface reference will try to release the interface and still crash in the `TNoRefCountObject` situation. If you free the object directly, you need to typecast the interface reference to `Pointer` to avoid that release, eg: `Pointer(MyListArray[i]) := nil;` or `PPointer(@MyListArray[i])^ := nil;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It will not crash if the object is still alive like it is in my example. What I forgot to copy is original line which constructs the object instance.

Comment: "*It will not crash if the object is still alive*" - good point, I missed that detail in your example. Still, it's worth making this clear, in case someone were to try to do something like this: `FreeAndNil(MyListArray[i] as TMyList); MyListArray[i] := nil;` That would fail.

Comment: I might sound a bit pedantic...  But in the first sentence, I think it would be preferable to say something like "interface reference always follow reference counting semantics (even if the backing object doesn't enable/support it)".  In its current form, I feel it could be slightly confusing for someone who does not understand the topic well.

Comment: @KenBourassa I updated the answer. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. That explains some things. But still, why is _intfClear called for an object which always returns -1 in _Release? It should only be called when this reaches zero as I understand it?

Comment: Compiler does not know what is the implementation within the actual object. It only knows that it has to deal with interface reference at the compile time. Destruction of the object happens within the `_Release` method if the reference count filed reaches 0. You will be able to understand better if you take a look at the implementation of `_Release` method in `TInterfacedObject`.